# Noob Concern: T-SQL Nesting Subquery

Tags: sql, t-sql

I've got a table named nobel with the following fields:  yr, subject and winner.

This table represents winners of nobel prize winners in a variety of subjects over the years.

I am looking for the years in which the Physics Prize was awarded but no Chemistry prize.

I was thinking the answer would look something like the following:

```
SELECT yr FROM nobel 
WHERE subject ('Chemistry') IN (SELECT subject FROM nobel WHERE subject = 'Physics')
```

I'm fairly certain I've got the syntax wrong... and i'm not certain i'm going down the right road.  Help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT yr 
FROM nobel n1 
WHERE n1.subject = 'Physics'
AND yr NOT IN (SELECT yr FROM nobel WHERE subject = 'Chemistry')
```

Comment: For the drill I was doing I ended up having to add DISTINCT yr, but your answer led the way!  Thank you sir!

Comment: If you used my EXCEPT version, DISTINCT isn't required

Comment: I was doing a drill on sqlzoo.  They must be using an older version of sql server as the foundation for their drills... because it didn't work.  But that was a cool way of doing it that I will have to remember.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're using SQL Server 2000, [EXCEPT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) works on 2005+.

```
    SELECT yr
      FROM nobel 
     WHERE subject = 'Chemistry'
EXCEPT
    SELECT yr
      FROM nobel
     WHERE subject = 'Physics'
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code will give you required results.

```
 SELECT n1.yr
    FROM nobel n1
    WHERE subject = 'physics'
        AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT yr
            FROM nobel n2
            WHERE subject = 'chemistry' AND n2.yr = n1.yr
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be heading down the wrong path. The where clause you have is essentially saying where 'Chemistry' = 'Physics' which will never be true.

What I think you need to do is to find out what years physics and chemistry were awarded, THEN find the years that only physics was awarded.

```
SELECT yr
FROM Nobel
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT SUM(1), yr
  FROM  Nobel
  WHERE subject = 'Chemistry'
  Group By yr
) as Chemistry
ON Chemistry.yr = Nobel.Yr
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT SUM(1), yr
  FROM  Nobel
  WHERE subject = 'Physics'
  Group By yr
) as Physics
ON Physics.yr = Nobel.yr

WHERE Physics.YR IS NOT NULL AND Chemistry.Yr IS NULL

GROUP BY yr
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do two derived tables and join them.

```
SELECT c.Year FROM 
c (SELECT Year, COUNT(*) FROM nobel where subject = 'chem' GROUP By Year) INNER JOIN
p (SELECT Year, COUNT(*) FROM nobel where subject = 'phy' GROUP By Year) ON c.Year = p.Year
WHERE c.Count != 0 and p.Count = 0
```